# Convert a string from laravel controller to javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I would like to convert a string value that I fetch from my database and convert it to a date variable in the view using javascript

I have tried out the following code;

```
var date = moment({!! $cheque->cheque_date !!}).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I am getting the following result when I console log the date variable.
1970-01-01

Comment: what is the value of `$cheque->cheque_date`

Comment: @Ali the value is 2019-04-10. However, when I try to console log it I get a NaN error

Comment: You need javascript quotes around that php string output and probably a format argument for `moment(string, format)`

Comment: `var date = moment('{!! $cheque->cheque_date !!}').format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

Comment: @charlietfl and Haurn Yilmaz thank you for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add `"` quotations

checkout this

```
var date = moment("{{ $cheque->cheque_date }}").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

this will converted to

```
var date = moment("2019-04-10").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

while your code will be converted to

```
var date = moment(2019-04-10).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // no quotations
```

Comment: happy to help :)